# Navigation component: parcelable argument but get error Type mismatch: inferred type is Student but String was expected

Tags: android, kotlin, android-navigation, android-architecture-navigation, kotlin-android-extensions

In my root build.gradle I have `navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin` version `2.2.0-rc03`:

```
script{
   dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.3'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:2.2.0-rc03'
    }
}
```

In my navigation graph xml:

```
<fragment
        android:id="@+id/MyListFragment"
        android:name="com.foo.bar.ui.mylist.MyListFragment"
        android:label="My List">

        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_myListFragment_to_myDetailFragment"
            app:destination="@id/myDetailFragment" />

        <!--Here I pass parcelable type as argument-->
        <argument
            android:name="Student"
            app:argType="com.foo.core.model.Student"/>

    </fragment>
```

`Student` is a normal class.

```
package com.foo.core.model

@Parcelize
data class Student(val studentNumber: Int): Parcelable
```

In my fragment I do:

```
val student:Student=Student(123)
findNavController().navigate(actionMyListFragmentToMyDetailFragment(student))
```

When I build my project, I get compiler error:

```
Type mismatch: inferred type is Student but String was expected
```

Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put your `argument` in **MyDetailsFragment** not **MyListFragment** so

**MyListFragment**

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/MyListFragment"
    android:name="com.foo.bar.ui.mylist.MyListFragment"
    android:label="My List">

    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_myListFragment_to_myDetailFragment"
        app:destination="@id/MyDetailsFragment" />

</fragment>
```

**MyDetailsFragment**

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/MyDetailsFragment"
    android:name="com.foo.bar.ui.mylist.MyDetailsFragment"
    android:label="My Details">

    <argument
        android:name="Student"
        app:argType="com.foo.core.model.Student"/>

</fragment>
```